# How to point URL path to a wordpress folder

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I currently have two sites, hosted on the same server using Apache virtual hosts.

```
http://www.example.com  -> /var/www/sites/mysite (path to main website)
http://blog.example.com -> /var/www/sites/blog (path to wordpress folder)
```

I need my blog to be accessible from www.example.com/blog

I cannot move the wordpress installation into a 'blog' subdirectory of the mysite folder.

Using the Apache Alias directive, I can do the following in the configuration for www.example.com:

```
Alias /blog /var/www/sites/blog
```

and access the blog via www.example.com/blog

However the following fails to work with a 404

www.example.com/blog/a-permalink-post-title

I have also tried using the following but the 404 still persists.

```
AliasMatch /blog/(.*)$ /var/www/sites/blog/$1
```

The current virtual host configuration looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com
Alias /blog /var/www/sites/blog
DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/mysite
<Directory /var/www/sites/mysite>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and for blog.example.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName blog.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/blog
<Directory /var/www/sites/blog>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Would greatly appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Please improve information on your tree folders, it's not clear.

Comment: Any help with this, I have the same problem